# Update panel error in custom page when logging with a user other than the administrator

Tags: sharepoint

I made a custom page and added it to a MOSS 2007 site.
the custom page has an update panel and some ajax controls
when I'm logged in as an administrator with full control permissions, the page works fine.
but if another user with even Full control permission logs in and browse the page, an error appears:

The control with ID 'UpdatePanel2' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

where UpdatePanel2 id the id of the update panel in the page, and the strange thing is that the master page of the site has a script manager addded to it.

so what can be the reason of this ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the Common Behaviour when you dont approve the changes of the MasterPage after chaning the master page through SharePoint designer. To resolve this problem make sure that you have approved the changes of the MasterPage you did. Usually admin has fullpermission to view the unapproved changes as well, while normal users dont.

Comment: Thanks but could you please explain in more details what should I do exactly
thanks

Comment: have you edited the masterpage to include the ScriptManager? If yes, you need to right click it => Check-in => Publish a Major Version => View Approval Status in browser => Context Menu => Approve/Reject and approve the file.

Comment: Hi
but my site is a team site tempalte not a publishing site, so in the context menu of the master page item in the master page gallery there is no option for publishing major version or for approving/rejecting.
so is there a workaround for this ?
thanks

Comment: I dont know if this will make a difference but you can try connecting to the site through SharePoint Designer, locate the page that you need to publish, right click on it from the tree view and try to publish a major version from there.

Comment: team sites need Approval of Master Pages the same way Publishing sites do.

Comment: Hi all
I solved by opening the site with sharepoint designer, right click on the master page and set as default master page
thanks for your help